# Trying to fix the double input in my rock-paper-scissors game

Tags: python-3.x

I made this simple rock-paper-scissors game where at the end of the game i ask user for an input where depending on their input the program continues or it terminates.
Every time the game ends this message appears:
**"Press 'space' To RESTART or 'esc' to EXIT"**
I am using the keyboard module in python. Whenever user enters 'space' as an input the program not only restarts the game but also takes that space as an input.

This is how i am trying to take the input from user when the game starts.

```
def game_rps():

    got_valid_input  = False
    global user_move
    global cpu_move

    while got_valid_input == False:
        user_input = input("Your Turn:")

        if user_input == "r":
            user_move = "rock"
            got_valid_input == True
        elif user_input == "p":
            user_move = "paper"
            got_valid_input == True
        elif user_input == "s":
            user_move = "scissors"
            got_valid_input == True
        else:
            print("invalid move, try again")
            continue
```

This is how i tried to use the keyboard module to decide on whether to continue or exit the program.

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
        game_rps()
        print("Press 'space' To RESTART or 'esc' to EXIT") 
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
        break
        
sys.exit()
```

To fix this issue i changed `user_input == "r"` to `user_input == "r" or user_input == " r"`, after doing this the program works without any problems but i would still like to know how do i make it so pressing 'space' isn't considered as an input?